# Having problems while doing window Handle

Tags: java, window, size, handle, difference

While doing handle windows in selenium - Java, in Java it shows one 1 window open and if i tried with C# it shows 2 . I am not able to get the window handle of second window opened(Actually it is a message dialog box, i need to click on ok button and proceed to the parent window) in Java.Please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 0):

You should have searched for solution on internet and tried it yourself first, well below code might help you:

```
//Before you click, get main window handle
String mainhandle=driver.getWindowHandle();

//Enter code to click button

new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
.ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class)
.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

flag=0;

while(flag==0){
    try{
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        flag=1;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    }

driver.switchTo().window(mainhandle);
```